# Prove that for an increasing and differentiable function $f'(x) \ge 0$ holds.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

> Prove: If $f$ is a differentiable and increasing function then $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

**Proof from my class notes:**
$$ f'(x) = f'_+(x) = \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} \ge 0$$

this proof is short and ambiguous to me:
**Questions:**

1. Why is the limit $\ge 0$?
2. Why $f'(x) = f_+(x)$ (And therefore, also equals $f'_-(x)$)?

Thanks.

Comment: The limit of a nonnegative function is nonnegative.

Comment: Yes, of course. it is implied by the title, but I'll note that.

Comment: @UmbertoP. If you write $f'\ge 0$ you must assume its existence.

Comment: @UmbertoP., the function can be negative.

Comment: @Elimination, $\dfrac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$ must be nonnegative.

Comment: Since the function is increasing, so $f'(x+\delta x) \ge f'(x)$, which makes the difference quotient positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the fact that $f$ is increasing to see that if $\Delta x > 0$, $f(x+\Delta x) \ge f(x) \Rightarrow f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) \ge 0 \Rightarrow \frac{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x} \ge 0$.
Analogously for $\Delta x < 0$ you still have $\ge 0$.
Now using that if $g(x) \ge 0 \forall x \in U$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$, you get that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) \ge 0$$
as well.

Comment: Oh I understand. The inequality is preserved after taking the limit. Thanks!

Comment: @Elimination Yes, not so with the strict inequality btw. $g(x) > 0$ still only allows for $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $\Delta x>0$. Then it immediately follows from the 'increasing' part that $ f(x + \Delta x)- f(x) \geq 0$, and, since it is differentiable, the ratio is also positive.

Comment: thanks, I guess $\geq$ is better

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable and non-decreasing, then we know that:

$f=\int f' dx$. However, we can define $f'(x)=g(x)\mathbf{I}_{(-\infty,a)}(x) + h(x)\mathbf{I}_{(a,\infty)}(x) + \alpha{I}_{a}(x)$, where $g(x),h(x)>0$. Since the lebesgue measure of $\alpha{I}_{a}(x)=0$, we can make $\alpha$ be anything we want.

Therefore, it is not true if we allow point discontinuities.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $f$ is differentiable in $x$ then $f'(x)$ exsists, i.e. the limit exist, which exactly means that the side-limits are equal: $f'(x)=f'_{-}(x)=f'_{+}(x)$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of looking at this problem (different from your class notes):

What happens when $f'(x) < 0$ even at a single point $c$? Clearly this would mean that the there will be an interval $I$ containing $c$ such that $f(x) > f(c) $ for all $x \in I, x < c$ and $f(x) < f(c)$ for all $x \in I, x > c$. This goes contrary to the increasing nature of $f(x)$. Hence we must have $f'(x) \geq 0$. It should be noted that the equality can occur as can be seen with $f(x) = x^{3}$, $f'(x) = 0$ for $x = 0$ yet the function is strictly increasing everywhere.